# How to reset password on Kyocera FS-1920 printer

Tags: password

We are using this model in an office network environment with MacbookPros running Snow Leopard 10.6.7, the printer is connected by cable to a wifi router, we can print through wireless connection and so far it runs mostly fine. But some documents need suspiciously long time to get to the printing phase (like a 0.5MB jpg). I supposed that it might be because of some bad network settings of the printer that could be changed on its web interface, but certain pages require administrator username and password, which we don't know. I googled about how to reset the password for about an hour without any success. Does anyone know how to do it with this model? Or is there a default username/password?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I can see, the FS-1920 doesn't have a web interface.  It does have a network card, but it's controlled via the front panel.  Are you sure that's what you have?

Comment: Weird, I checked the [manual of the model](http://usa.kyoceramita.com/americas/jsp/upload/resource/12548/0/FS1920ENOGR1.2.pdf), and it has no section about the web interface. But what we have [does have a web interface](https://skitch.com/temaruk/8e84k/fullscreen). ?

Comment: Generally speaking you're not going to find very many "bad" network settings that could cause a print slow down like you mention - TCP/IP either works (right IP address, subnet mask, etc) or doesn't - for the most part.   You might need to contact kyocera directly...